# editing/creating custom fields - parse.com iOS sdk (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I would like to edit a custom field in my parse app using parse iOS sdk, however, the suggested way does not seem to work.

```
 var user = PFUser()
// other fields can be set just like with PFObject
user["phone"] = "415-392-0202" //ERROR: cannot assign a value of type string to a value of type any object?
```

The methods user.setValue and user.setObject does seem to update the value, but the change remains unseen in Parse.com web ui.

```
// facebookID is a string parse field
user?.setObject("OK!", forKey: "facebookID")
user?.setValue("OK!", forKey: "facebookID")
```

Is there any other way to edit custom fields on parse in swift?

Comment: Are you saving the user after the edit?

Comment: That was my problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those *do* work, the reason you're not seeing the changes in the dashboad is because you're not saving the user after that.

```
user.setObject("OK!", forKey: "faceBookID")
user.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: Please note that the *initial* save of a PFUser must be made with the signUp method.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any significant difference between setObject and setValue? Also, how do I save the user if I edit the info in web ui?

Comment: That's true! Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't even think that it could be the first save, but if that's the case then yes, you must use user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock()

Comment: If you edit in the web ui it will save automatically when you click out of that row. As for differences, I think (don't quote me on this because I can't entirely remember) that setValue is for bool fields

Comment: PFObject doesn't implement setValue:forKey:.  That method is part of KVO, and in parse, works only for scalar types (including bools).  I think just sticking with setObject:forKey: in all cases is easier on the brain.